# RobotFramework RIDE not opening

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython, robotframework

I have installed `robotframework` and `robotframework-ride` using `pip`. All the other required components are also updated. I am using Python 3.7.6 and Windows 10.
When I run RIDE, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\robotide\application\application.py", line 62, in OnInit
    self._plugin_loader.enable_plugins()
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\robotide\application\pluginloader.py", line 43, in enable_plugins
    p.enable_on_startup()
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\robotide\application\pluginconnector.py", line 52, in enable_on_startup
    self.enable()
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\robotide\application\pluginconnector.py", line 57, in enable
    self._plugin.enable()
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\robotide\recentfiles\recentfiles.py", line 44, in enable
    self._add_recent_files_to_menu()
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\robotide\recentfiles\recentfiles.py", line 114, in _add_recent_files_to_menu
    self.register_action(action)
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\robotide\pluginapi\plugin.py", line 204, in register_action
    action = self.__frame.actions.register_action(action_info)
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\robotide\ui\mainframe.py", line 751, in register_action
    self._menubar.register(action)
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\robotide\ui\actiontriggers.py", line 60, in register
    menu.add_menu_item(action)
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\robotide\ui\actiontriggers.py", line 98, in add_menu_item
    menu_item = self._construct_menu_item(action)
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\robotide\ui\actiontriggers.py", line 107, in _construct_menu_item
    menu_item = self._create_menu_item(action)
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\robotide\ui\actiontriggers.py", line 139, in _create_menu_item
    pos = action.get_insertion_index(self.wx_menu)
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\robotide\action\action.py", line 40, in get_insertion_index
    return self._insertion_point.get_index(menu)
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\robotide\action\actioninfo.py", line 286, in get_index
    index = self._find_position_in_menu(menu)
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\robotide\action\actioninfo.py", line 296, in _find_position_in_menu
    if self._get_menu_item_name(item).lower() == self._item.lower():
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\robotide\action\actioninfo.py", line 301, in _get_menu_item_name
    return self._shortcut_remover.split(item.GetLabel())[0]
AttributeError: 'MenuItem' object has no attribute 'GetLabel'
OnInit returned false, exiting...
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
wx._core.wxAssertionError: C++ assertion "GetEventHandler() == this" failed at ..\..\src\common\wincmn.cpp(475) in wxWindowBase::~wxWindowBase(): any pushed event handlers must have been removed
```

I can't deduce whether I am doing something wrong. I have installed RIDE previously on this PC and others as well and this is the first time I am running into this error.
Kindly help.

Comment: wx.MenuItem.GetLabel() is deprecated, replaced by wx.MenuItem.GetLabelText(). I assume robotframework requires an older version of wx.python or wxwidgets. Check that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use newest wxPython version 4.1.0, you will have to install the current development version of RIDE (2.0b1.dev1) from source code, Otherwise, you should install version 4.0.7.post2.

See project page at https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE

Comment: Yes I figured it out. Was going to post it as an answer. But thank you for your help.